# Django - NoReverseMatch - Reverse for 'contextual' with keyword arguments '{'api': '9933124422'}' not found

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

**Html**

```
{% for well_instance, values in well_info %}
<tr>
  {% for value in values %}
  <td><a href="{% url 'eric_base:contextual' api=well_instance.api %}">{{ value }}</a></td>
  {% endfor %}
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

**views.py**

```
class WellList_ListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'well_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'well_info'
    model = models.WellInfo

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # get string representation of field names in list
        context['fields'] = [field.name for field in models.WellInfo._meta.get_fields()]

        # nested list that has all objects' all attribute values
        context['well_info_values'] = [[getattr(instance, field) for field in context['fields']] for instance in context['well_info']]

        # includes well instance objects & values string list for each well
        context['well_info'] = zip([instance for instance in context['well_info']], context['well_info_values'])

        return context

class ContextualMainView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'contextual_main.html'
```

**eric_base/urls.py**

```
app_name = 'eric_base'

urlpatterns = [

        re_path(r'^(?P<api>[\w-]+)/$', base_views.ContextualMainView.as_view(), name='contextual'),

]
```

**project/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [

    path('well_list/', include([

        re_path(r'^$', views.WellList_ListView.as_view(), name='well_list'),
        re_path(r'^create/$', views.AddWell_CreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
        re_path(r'^contextual/$', include('eric_base.urls')),

        ]))
```

**models.py**

```
# Create your models here.
class WellInfo(models.Model):
    api = models.CharField(max_length=100, primary_key=True)
    well_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    phase = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    start_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_updates = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.well_name
```

**Error Message**

```
NoReverseMatch at /well_list/

Reverse for 'contextual' with keyword arguments '{'api': '9933124422'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['well_list\\/contextual/$(?P<api>[\\w-]+)/$']
```

I really don't understand what's wrong with this. Judging from the fact that I get a non-null value for `{'api': '9933124422'}`, I think I correctly injected the dictionary from `{% url 'eric_base:contextual' api=well_instance.api %}`, but still its giving me an error. Please help!

Comment: let see your `ContextualMainView`

Comment: @SancaKembang sorry, and thanks for pointing out. I just added it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You sould change your `TemplateView` to `DetailView`, because `TemplateView` doesn't have `get_object` method. Eg in your case:

```
class ContextualMainView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'contextual_main.html'
```

to;

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

from eric_base.models import WellInfo


class ContextualMainView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'contextual_main.html'
    model = WellInfo

    def get_object(self):
        return get_object_or_404(self.model, api=self.kwargs['api'])
```

***See also this docs:***

- http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.base/TemplateView/
- http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.0/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/

---

After following the discussion, the actual problem is here. The character `$` should use for the final url and shouldn't be used if you have an another include urls.

```
re_path(r'^contextual/$', include('eric_base.urls'))
```

to;

```
re_path(r'^contextual/', include('eric_base.urls'))
```

Comment: I don't know whats wrong, but I'm still getting the exact same error. I changed to Detail you and copied your get_object method but it still won't work

Comment: the debug pages says that there's something wrong with this line: `<td><a href="{% url 'eric_base:contextual' api=well_instance.api %}">{{ value }}</a></td>`

Comment: I think your problem in this case `well_list\\/contextual/$(?P<api>[\\w-]+)/$` , let me see your `urls.py` for `well_list/contextual`

Comment: the app urls was actually an extention of the project url, which is well_list/contextual. I updated the codes

Comment: omg thank you so much, like SOOO much. It works!! I really can't thank you enough for this. Really thanks for helping omg

Comment: i've upvoted all ur most recent answers... ur reputation went up by 150 something now